# 2 errors configuring drupal in Ubuntu server 10.04

Tags: drupal-7, ubuntu-10.04

I am setting up Drupal in Ubuntu server and I have the following errors, and not how to fix them.

```
User error: Failed to connect to memcache server: 127.0.0.1:11211 in dmemcache_object()
(line 415 of /var/www/ujc/sites/ujc/modules/contrib/memcache/dmemcache.inc).

PDOException: could not find driver in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of 
/var/www/ujc/includes/lock.inc).
```

Answer (score 2):

First check the running status of memcached, type this in terminal

```
/etc/init.d/memcached status
```

If is not running type:

```
/etc/init.d/memcached start
```

For the second one i suggest you to run this code:

```
foreach (PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver) {
    echo $driver . PHP_EOL;
}
```

and see if you have installed sqlite driver for pdo